# NSPredicate check string length

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, string

I need to be able to build an NSPredicate that checks the length of a string.

My predicate is:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"storyText.length > 20"];
```

I know that NSPredicate does not recognise `length` as a property.

Solutions on SO indicate using a regex is the way to go but I haven't figured out how to do length > 20. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this for a Core Data fetch request? Otherwise your predicate should work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
NSPredicate *stringLengthPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(StoryText evaluatedObject, NSDictionary *bindings) {
            return [evaluatedObject length] > 20;
        }];
```

[Source](http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this perhaps:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"position == %@ AND text MATCHES %@", pos, @".{21,}"];
```

It should match anything at least 21 characters in length.